# Problems with 100% height

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to use a side panel with a width of 20% and a height of 100% so that they will re-size depending on browser width and height etc. I'm having a problem with the height (100%) part of the CSS, it doesn't seem to fit the entire height of the browser window though - it just displays 100% of what's in the side panel.

How can I make the side panel reach the bottom of the page no matter how much content is inside of it?

```css
#sidebar{
    float:left;
    position: relative;
    width: 20%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: red;
}
```

Comment: Is there another element around the sidebar? Some sort of wrapper? We need that code too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Height 100% is always a pain.

Make sure that, `html, body` also have `height: 100%` and any `div` that's wrapping it.

Answer (score 1):

When you set something with percentages, you must always consider "percent of what?" It's always the parent of the element. So what is the parent set to? If there is no defined height in units for the parent, percentage has no reference.

Comment: Yeah this might be the problem its within a div called main_content which is set to 100% aswell can I get around that cos I need that div to be the height of the browser too.


#main_content{

 float:left;
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 
 }

Comment: @DanFarrell The viewport is what you look at in the window and it's the parent of html which is the parent of body. So setting those to 100% will use the viewport as their reference.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem on a project I was working on, I fixed it thus:

```css
#sidebar{
    min-height:100%;
    height:auto !important;
    height: 100%;
    //add other styling needed
}
```