# Min height not working properly?

Tags: css, internet-explorer, firefox, flexbox

I am trying to create a DIV that will have a minimum height of 100%, which is not working in FireFox / IE. It works only if use the "height" property.

Chrome is behaving correctly.

```
<style>
    .page{
        min-height:100%;
        border:1px solid black;
    }
</style>
<html>
    <div class="page">
        With firefox / IE, this div is not stretching to take 100% of the total page height.
    </div>
</html>
```

**Update:**

I understand that I need to define the height of the body/html. That makes sense. But even with this solution, I still cannot use min-height for a child div. See the below example. The child div is not taking 33% of the parent div. (In FIREFOX and IE)

```
<style>
    .page{
        min-height:100%;
        border:1px solid black;
    }

    html,
    body {
        height: 100%;
    }

    .child{
        min-height:33%;
        border:1px solid black;
        display:flex;
    }

</style>
<html>
    <div class="page">
        Parent div
    <div class="child">
        With firefox / IE, this CHILD div is not stretching to take 33% of the container.
    </div>
</div>
</html>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [min-height does not work with body](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3740722/min-height-does-not-work-with-body) and a number of same answers found by searching SO.

Comment: [Here is my answer from six years ago](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8327304/problems-with-100-height/8327394#8327394)

Comment: Did you read my duplicate answer from six years ago I linked to which directly addresses your updated question?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You also need to give the `html` and `body` a height

```
html, body {
  height: 100%;
}
```

---

Update 1, after a question edit

With that new markup, also `.page` need `height: 100%`

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}

.page {
  height: 100%;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.child {
  min-height: 100%;
  border: 1px solid red;
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<div class="page">
  <div class="child">
    With firefox / IE, this CHILD div is not stretching to take 100% of the container.
  </div>
</div>
```

---

Update 2, based on a comment

Use Flexbox and viewport units `vh` instead, it will work much better

```css
body {
  display: flex;                 /*  IE need this for its 'min-height' bug  */
}

.page {
  min-height: 100vh;
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.child {
  flex-grow: 1;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div class="page">
  <div class="child">
  
    With firefox / IE, this CHILD div is not stretching to take 100% of the container.<br>
    
    With firefox / IE, this CHILD div is not stretching to take 100% of the container.<br>
    
    With firefox / IE, this CHILD div is not stretching to take 100% of the container.<br>
    
    With firefox / IE, this CHILD div is not stretching to take 100% of the container.<br>
    
    With firefox / IE, this CHILD div is not stretching to take 100% of the container.<br>
    
    With firefox / IE, this CHILD div is not stretching to take 100% of the container.<br>
    
    With firefox / IE, this CHILD div is not stretching to take 100% of the container.<br>
    
    With firefox / IE, this CHILD div is not stretching to take 100% of the container.<br>
    
    With firefox / IE, this CHILD div is not stretching to take 100% of the container.<br>
    
    With firefox / IE, this CHILD div is not stretching to take 100% of the container.<br>
    
    With firefox / IE, this CHILD div is not stretching to take 100% of the container.<br>
    
    With firefox / IE, this CHILD div is not stretching to take 100% of the container.<br>
    
    With firefox / IE, this CHILD div is not stretching to take 100% of the container.<br>
    
    With firefox / IE, this CHILD div is not stretching to take 100% of the container.<br>
    
    With firefox / IE, this CHILD div is not stretching to take 100% of the container.<br>
    
    With firefox / IE, this CHILD div is not stretching to take 100% of the container.<br>
    
  </div>
</div>
```

Which also will work with the `min-height: 33%`

```css
body {
  display: flex;                 /*  IE need this for its 'min-height' bug  */
}

.page {
  min-height: 100vh;
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.child {
  min-height: 33%;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div class="page">
  <div class="child">
  
    With firefox / IE, this CHILD div is not stretching to take 100% of the container.<br>
    
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @DavidSomekh Updated my answer. Do note, you need to make sure you put it all-in in the first place, as with this edit you made my initial answer invalid, which is not how to do it. If an edit invalidate the given answers, you are better of posting a new question.

Comment: This answer brings me back to my original problem, that the height cannot exceed 100%. (Because it becomes static). Anyway around that?

Comment: @DavidSomekh I guessed you would say that :), so my 2nd update solves it

Answer (score 3):

The percentage value of `min-height` and `height` properties do not work if the direct parent of the element doesn't have an explicit `height` applied using CSS.

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/min-height)

> The percentage is calculated with respect to the height of the
> generated box's containing block. If the height of the containing
> block is not specified explicitly (i.e., it depends on content
> height), and this element is not absolutely positioned, the percentage
> value is treated as 0.

The only way to do it is to add another `div` inside the parent `div` and explicitly set its height to 100% then insert the child `div` inside it then the `min-height` will work

```
<html>
  <body>
  <style>
    html, body {
      height: 100%;
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
  }
    .page{
        min-height:100%;
        border:1px solid black;
    }
    .wrapper {
      height: 100%;
    }
    .child {
      min-height: 33%;
      background: yellow;
    }
  </style>
    <div class="page">
        <div class="wrapper">
          <div class="child"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

To be honest, I'm not sure why it even works with the height property. When you're using percentage heights in CSS, the root element (html, body) needs to have a defined height.

This is because percentages are percentages of the parent. If the root element has no defined height, then no height can be calculated from it.

So to give the root element a height, you set it to 100% like this:

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
}
.page{
  min-height:100%;
  border:1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div class="page">
  With firefox / IE, this div is not stretching to take 100% of the total page height.
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case solution was use `min-height: 100vh`

Answer (score 0):

In the case of table **`<th> \ <tr>`** the `min-height` is not working, but you can use `heigh`, and in this situation will behave as `min-height`.

Answer (score -1):

Try adding to your CSS code this:

```
.page{
   min-height: 100%;
   -moz-min-height: 100%;
   border: 1px solid black;
}
```

Sometimes browsers do not act in the same way, and you need to add some things. Moz for mozilla firefox. `-webkit-styleGoesHere` is for Chrome.
I hope this helped.

Comment: `min-height` doesn't require a vendor prefix